# Matplotlib wrong auto - default Y axis order

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I use single axis plot with default auto Y axis and can't set the asscending order on Y axis:

```
import csv

import urllib.request

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np


x=[]

url = "http://santakey.ddns.net/sts2.txt"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
lines = [l.decode('utf-8') for l in response.readlines()]
plots = csv.reader(lines)

for row in plots:

x.append(row[6])

plt.plot(x)

plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[plot error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgYrK.jpg)

Comment: You probably need to convert the strings to numbers: `x.append(float(row[6]))`. Note that this type of problems is solved automatically with pandas `pd.read_csv()`

Comment: @JohanC great answer, it works !! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try `float` row append instead just append row

```
import csv
import urllib.request
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x=[]
url = "http://santakey.ddns.net/sts2.txt"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
lines = [l.decode('utf-8') for l in response.readlines()]
plots = csv.reader(lines)

for row in plots:
  x.append(float(row[6]))

plt.plot(x)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Get the [output](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1v664QZAeilEUHZIwadru9FMDRVfl6L4M?usp=sharing)